# Xively request log seems stuck on "Waiting for requests" in two different attempted tutorial examples

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, xively

I followed the tutorial at: https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi/

And it almost worked. My python code compiled and ran just fine, and does seem to be sending something to Xively, as I get a stream of messages on the Pi like this:

Reading load average
Updating Xively feed with calus: 0.08

and so on... With no errors. But on the Developer Page (Dashboard?) The Request Log seems to be stuck on "Waiting for requests" with a spinning wheel.

Question 1: Shouldn't I be seeing some activity in the Request Log?

Furthermore, I can click "Graphs" in the Channels section of the same page, and see that data was sent, but it doesn't scroll. I have to spam F5 to see any updates that have posted since I first clicked "Graphs".

Question 2: The graph should scroll as updated data streams in, right?

I don't think I missed any steps in the guide. And running the program the first time did successfully create the channel and start streaming updates.

One other odd detail, the same thing happened when I ran the mobile phone package tracker example on my iPhone. "Waiting for requests" never updated, even though the app seemed to accept the id and key and ran fine on the phone end...

I'm lost, and I'm not sure what I did wrong, or what other info to provide. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to work this out? Seems like the same broken behavior in two totally different examples on different devices. 99% sure it's my fault, but I'd love to figure this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem fixed itself. I logged back onto the developer page today and noticed that the Request Log had updated. My Raspberry Pi code was not running, but now I can see yesterday's requests in the log.

Since I had the same problem on my Raspberry Pi and on my iPhone (failure of the Request Log to show anything but "Waiting for requests" and a failure of the graphs to update/scroll without me hitting F5 over and over), I don't think it was the Pi or the phone at fault.

I suggest the following three possibilities: 
1: Perhaps it can take a day or so for a new Xively account to start working? All of my problems were on Day 1 of my new Xively account. 
2: Perhaps there was a general problem with the system yesterday. Maybe only with newly formed channels or accounts.
3: Maybe someone behind the scenes saw my post and fixed my account.

Anyway, everything seems to be working fine now on the Pi. Time to get to work on a "real" project!